# Can't install gulp locally. when I run "npm install gulp --save-dev" command in cmd it's fails

Tags: node.js

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\projects\gulp\npm-debug.log
here are errors that I get after running "npm install gulp --save-dev" command.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have your own "gulp" package at `D:\projects\gulp`, you cant install gulp with `npm install gulp --save-dev` because it would be a dependency of itself, like the error says. The `name` property in your `package.json` cannot be "gulp" if you want to install gulp as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
I changed name and installed it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `package.json` the `name` attribute is set to `gulp`.

Set it to something else.